# Geopandas error while trying to union geometries

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe like the following:

```
gdf
    geometry
0   POLYGON ((-3.64099 40.54597, -3.63906 40.53709...
1   POLYGON ((-3.68162 40.51283, -3.67968 40.50395...
2   POLYGON ((-3.72221 40.47967, -3.72026 40.47078...
3   POLYGON ((-3.70095 40.49181, -3.69900 40.48293...
4   POLYGON ((-3.71060 40.48130, -3.70866 40.47241...
```

If I plot it I get:

```
gdf.boundary.plot()
```

[image]

I would like to merge together the adjacent polygons. This is what I am trying to do:

```
gdf2 = gpd.geoseries.GeoSeries([geom for geom in gdf.unary_union.geoms])
```

but I get the following error

```
GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing
```

If I check the validity of the geometries I get:

```
for i in gdf.index:
    print(gdf['geometry'][i].exterior.type)

LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
LinearRing
```

Comment: To check the validity of the geometries, you should do `.is_valid`, `.is_simple`, `.is_empty` not `.exterior.type`.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this exception when using the `unary_union()` method on a Geopandas `DataSeries`. It turned out not to be due to a problem with the code but rather a [bug in some of Geopandas' dependencies](https://github.com/pygeos/pygeos/issues/447). This issue report contains the details, which, to be honest, I do not fully understand. To make a long story short, I was able to resolve the problem by upgrading the `pygeos` package to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade pygeos
```